# Why am I getting syntax error 22-322 and error 76-322

Tags: sas, proc-sql

My code is the below.  I am not advanced in SAS or SQL my statement is below from SAS Enterprise Guide 8.2 using Proc sql.
What I want to do is by unique PrescriberID to have the RX_PMPM, DrugCost_PMPM,PDL Rate GDR Rate  right next to each PresriberID

I am getting syntax error
ERROR 22-322
ERROR 76-322

```
proc sql;
create table work.ABC_2020_out as
select  Distinct PrescriberId, 
from work.VitMDKPI_Report
        sum(PaidAmt)/count(distinct CardholderId) as RX_PMPM,
        sum(DrugCost)/count(distinct PrescriptionNumber) as DrugCost_PMPM,
            Count (PDL) as Total_NONANDPDL,
        Count (BrandGenericCode) as Total_BrandGeneric,
        Case when PDL=Y then 'PREFPDL'
        Case when BrandGenericCode=G then 'Generic'
        End
        PDL/Total_NONANDPDL as PDL Rate
        Generic/Total_BrandGeneric as GDR Rate
        Group by PrescriberId;


quit;
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to do with that query.  Also specify which version of SAS you are using EG to connect to, since the PROC SQL code is run by the SAS session and not by the EG user interface you used to submit the code.  Posting the lines from the SAS log helps as SAS will attempt to mark what characters in the program are confusing it.

Answer (score 0):

The first error that the parser will see is that this section is invalid.

```
select Distinct PrescriberId,
from work.VitMDKPI_Report
```

Because of the comma at the end of the first line you are asking to select the variable named `from` and name it `work.VitMDKPI_Report`, which is not a valid name for a variable because of the period and the syntax is not valid because PROC SQL needs the `as` keyword when setting the name for a variable.

You seem to have put the FROM clause into the middle of the list of variables.  It should go after the list of variables and before the GROUP BY clause.

There are other issues including what looks like a mal formed CASE clause, attempts to reference a variable created in the SELECT clause without using the `CALCULATED` keyword and possibly invalid variable names.  But those will be harder to diagnosis without some example data and expected output for that data.

Comment: My question was answered from the combination of everyone’s answer.   I did not structure query right.  Thanks everyone.  It works now and I had a lot of rework based on answers.  I am glad I found this sight,